# Agregar datos a diccionario anidado y si no existe llave que la cree

Tags: python, lista, pandas, diccionarios, clase-anidada

necesito leer un log línea por línea e ir armando una especie de estructura JSON para luego convertirlo a DataFrame, el problema que me encontré es que en mi script con el comando ej: update({"VLAN": data[0]}) agrego como diccionario los datos que necesito de la línea, pero  cuando encuentra otra línea con misma "llave" que también debería agregarla, el comando reemplaza el dato existente por el nuevo.
Como podría agregar datos a la llave sin que reemplace los datos ya existentes, seria una estructura tipo {llave:["dato1","dato2", etc]}  algo si no?

Ejemplo de log (adjunto (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8rOjg_boLUdy7K6oML0-OzXfoP-qrSs/view?usp=sharing), no logro insertarlo en aquí):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el script utilizado:

```
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten
fail = []
i = -1

for line in f:
    
     data = line.split()
         
     if 'show networking address role iubcp' in line:                
            fail.append({'Alarma': data[7],'dato':{}})
            i += 1
        
            for line in f:
                data = line.split(':') # separo por ':'                   
                if '_iub_' in line: 
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({"VLAN": data[0]}) # aca el problema con update me reemplaza el valor buscado                       
                elif 'address     :' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({"address":[data[1]]})## aca el problema con update me reemplaza el valor buscado 
                elif 'owner' in line:
                    fail[i]["dato"].update({"owner":[data[1]]})# aca el problema con update me reemplaza el valor buscado 
                                    
                elif "root@" in line:
                    break
          
g = [flatten(d) for d in fail]
df= pd.DataFrame(g)
```

obtengo lo siguiente, que seria solo los datos de las ultimas líneas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isvo. Si puedes hacer la estructura que deseas. Recuerda que la Key de un elemento de un diccionario Python siempre es única porque funciona como un índice y nos sirve para apuntar al elemento que deseamos acceder.

En tu caso para crear la "estructura" que deseas, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
myDicionario = {"llave":[]}

myDicionario["llave"].append(data[0])

print(myDicionario)
```

- Creas un diccionario y agregas un elemento que tiene como key el nombre "llave" y como valor una lista de python vacía.
- Accedes al elemento que deseas especificando la key y como el valor es una lista de python, puedes usar el método append para agregar un elemento a esa lista vacía.
- imprimes el diccionario

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias @CalumRakk